# Generate SaS Token using Python

Tags: python, azure

So I took directly from Azure (https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security) a Python code to generate the SaS Token. I made the necessary adaptations for my application, but when I use the generated token to send data via POST it returns the following message:

"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:c8b0d18b771e465081aa9324293adf73-G:1-TimeStamp:09/08/2020 19:53:52"

I know how to generate the token using Azure tools in VS Code, but I would like this generation to be incorporated in the code. Below is the code I am using. (Of course, replacing Device ID, Iot Hub Name and the key with those available on the microsoft portal.)

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha256
from time import time
from urllib import parse
from hmac import HMAC


def generate_sas_token(uri, key, policy_name, expiry=3600):
    ttl = time() + expiry
    sign_key = "%s\n%d" % ((parse.quote_plus(uri)), int(ttl))
    #print (sign_key)
    signature = b64encode(HMAC(b64decode(key), sign_key.encode('utf-8'), sha256).digest())

    rawtoken = {
        'sr' :  uri,
        'sig': signature,
        #'se' : str(int(ttl))
    }

    if policy_name is not None:
        rawtoken['skn'] = policy_name

    rawtoken['se'] = str(int(ttl))

    return 'SharedAccessSignature ' + parse.urlencode(rawtoken)


resource_uri = IoTHubName + ".azure-devices.net" + "/" + "devices" + "/" + deviceID
policy_name = "iothubowner"

uri = resource_uri
key = "primary key="
expiry = 3600
policy= "iothubowner"

print (generate_sas_token(uri, key, policy, expiry))
```

Comment: Has your problem been solved and is there any progress?

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

Following the tutorial, step by step, I can get the desired result. So it can be said that this service is at least available to me.

**Suggested troubleshooting steps:**

1. Re-create the `iot` service, select a different region, and select other parameters different from the current one when creating it.
2. Use the same code for testing, which can be the same as mine.
3. If it is successful, it is recommended to `raise a support ticket` on portal to check where the original service problem occurred. If it fails, you can also ask them what to do and official suggestions.

***PRIVIOUS***

The value of key not start with `primary key=`.

And I found my primary key in `iothubowner`. And use your test code which like offical recommand. It works for me.

[image]

You can see my result in screenshot.

[image]

In my snippets code, the part with `*` is where I operate on the portal, and other codes have not been modified.

```
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode
from hashlib import sha256
from time import time
from urllib import parse
from hmac import HMAC

def generate_sas_token(uri, key, policy_name, expiry=3600):
    ttl = time() + expiry
    sign_key = "%s\n%d" % ((parse.quote_plus(uri)), int(ttl))
    #print sign_key
    signature = b64encode(HMAC(b64decode(key), sign_key.encode('utf-8'), sha256).digest())

    rawtoken = {
        'sr' :  uri,
        'sig': signature,
        'se' : str(int(ttl))
    }

    if policy_name is not None:
        rawtoken['skn'] = policy_name

    return 'SharedAccessSignature ' + parse.urlencode(rawtoken)

IoTHubName="pan****ub"
deviceID="test*****eid1"

resource_uri = IoTHubName + ".azure-devices.net" + "/" + "devices" + "/" + deviceID
policy_name = "iothubowner"

uri = resource_uri
key = "cPn4nuFMiN******J4/ojFtA9YV22OAc="
expiry = 3600
policy= "iothubowner"

print (generate_sas_token(uri, key, policy, expiry))
```

***My operations in portal.***

Just add create a device, and authentication type choose `Symmetric key`.

[image]

Comment: So I used his code, just like mine it generates a SaS key. However, when I try to use it to send data I get the same answer:
<Response [401]>
>>> print(resp.content)
b'{"Message":"ErrorCode:IotHubUnauthorizedAccess;Unauthorized","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:8e40e92b617949519c2bcc904d855a80-G:3-TimeStamp:09/10/2020 13:27:20"}'

Comment: @AndrezaBorchardt If you follow my steps and still get this error message, then there may be a problem with the creation of your IoT service. You can raise a support ticket on portal. They will help you and check logs.

Comment: @AndrezaBorchardt Has your problem been solved? Is there any progress?